# How to distinguish between two calls of the same method based on the argumetns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm using `sinon` to stub functions of the Google Drive in my NodeJS application. I do two different calls of the `create` method under the same test (I can't do restore between calls):

```
// Call 1:
drive.files.create({ 'requestBody': requestBody, 'media': media });

// Call 2:
drive.files.create({ 'resource': resource });
```

In order to stub, I could do something like:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(drive.files, 'create').returns({
  'status': 200,
  'data': {
    'files': [{ 'id': id }]
  }
});
```

This stub, actually stubs both calls but what if I want to have a successful first call and fail on the second call? How do I distinguish between the two calls (maybe) based on the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stub.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);` API.

> It is also useful to create a stub that can act differently in response to different arguments.

E.g.

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('72234931', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const drive = {
      files: {
        create(opts) {},
      },
    };

    const stub = sinon.stub(drive.files, 'create');

    stub.withArgs({ requestBody: 'requestBody', media: 'media' }).returns({
      status: 200,
      data: {
        files: [{ id: 1 }],
      },
    });
    stub.withArgs({ resource: 'resource' }).returns({ status: 500 });

    const r1 = drive.files.create({ requestBody: 'requestBody', media: 'media' });
    sinon.assert.match(r1, { status: 200, data: { files: [{ id: 1 }] } });

    const r2 = drive.files.create({ resource: 'resource' });
    sinon.assert.match(r2, { status: 500 });
  });
});
```